# Evaluating $\int_C \frac{dz}{(e^{2 \pi z}+1)^2}$ on the upper half-circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to compute the following

> $$
> \int_C \frac{dz}{(e^{2 \pi z}+1)^2} \quad C=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1 \textrm{ for } \Im(z)\ge0, \quad |\Re(z)|\leq 1 \textrm{ for }\Im(z)=0\}.
> $$

*Solution:* 
I know that $C$ is the upper-half circle and looking for the singularities
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{e^{2 \pi z}+1} \Longrightarrow e^{2\pi z}=-1\iff z=\frac{1}{2}i.$$
Then it belongs to the interior of $C$. My issue is that I can't apply the Cauchy Integral Formula directly. On the other hand, I was thinking to use series expansion, but it doesn't look nice. For sure I should use the residue theorem, but for that I need to express $f(z)$  as a Laurent series.

thanks

Comment: Yes, you're accurate. Sorry I forgot to put the absolute value. I'll write down the solution.

Comment: I don't know if my advice was actually that great cause there's still a potentially confusing limit you have to take (which you can do with series expansions or what have you) so I deleted it. It's probably easiest to just let $z=y+i/2$ and then develop the expansion as $a/y^2+b/y+\ldots.$

Comment: That's the thing. I tried to make a substitution  $w=e^{2 \pi z}$, but I think the contour must change too.

Comment: Yes I think calculating the residue directly makes the most sense, as in the answer I just posted.

Comment: Have you tried to exploit the fact that $e^{2\pi z}+1=e^{\pi z}\left(e^{\pi z}+\frac{1}{e^{\pi z}}\right)=
e^{\pi z}\left(e^{-i (i \pi z)}+e^{i(i \pi z)}\right)=2e^{\pi z}\cos{(i\pi z)}$?

Answer (score 3):

We want the residue for $\frac{1}{(e^{2\pi z}+1)^2}$ about $i/2,$ so let $z=y+i/2$ and do the expansion about $y=0$. We have $$ e^{2\pi(y+i/2)}+1 = 1-e^{2\pi y}$$ so we just need to expand $(e^{2\pi y}-1)^{-2}.$ We get $$\frac{1}{(e^{2\pi y}-1)^2} \approx \frac{1}{(2\pi y+\frac{1}{2}(2\pi y)^2)^2} = \frac{1}{(2\pi y)^2}\frac{1}{(1+\pi y)^2} \approx \frac{1}{(2\pi y)^2}(1-2\pi y) \\= \frac{1}{(2\pi y)^2} - \frac{1}{2\pi y} $$ so we get a residue of $-\frac{1}{2\pi}.$ So assuming the closed half-circle is traversed counterclockwize, we get a result of $-i.$